# How do I delay send commands in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

How do I delay [`Send`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) commands in AutoHotkey?

If AutoHotkey sends the keypresses faster than a program can register the inputs, words can end up mistyped with missing letters. (`stuff` ends up like `stf`, or `wasd squad` ends up like `wsdsqad`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SetKeyDelay`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) is what you need.

Note: `SetKeyDelay` is not obeyed by [`SendInput`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail); there is no delay between keystrokes in that mode. This same is true for `Send` when `SendMode Input` is in effect.

Answer (score 5):

SetKeyDelay, Delay between keystrokes in milliseconds, PressDuration in milliseconds

Of course this doesn't work with SendInput formats, but it does work with Send and ControlSend commands

So if you wanted a half-second delay between keypresses and each key to be held down for a quarter of a second, it would look like this:

```
SetKeyDelay, 500, 250
```

A practical example would be:

```
SetKeyDelay, 500, 250

Send Sincerely,{enter}John Smith
```

In this way, there would be a brief pause between keypresses and each key would be pressed a lot more like a real person would, thereby alleviating your probem of autohotkey sending keypresses faster than they can be registered.